# import a created class in jsp

Tags: servlets

ive got a servlet with a class file contained within file path webapps/ass2/WEB-INF/classes/User.class, the class represents a user bean required for my application. In jsp, ive go the imports organised as `<%@page import="mypck.User" %>. im being thrown an error by apache tomcat when i try to load the page,

```
An error occurred at line: 12 in the jsp file: /fourm.jsp
User cannot be resolved to a type
9: 
10: <head>
11: <%
12: User user = (User)session.getAttribute("userBean");
13: 
14: String username = user.getName();
15:
```

i guess i havent imported the class correctly then? my question is: how do i import this class to the jsp file

Answer (score 2):

> *a class file contained within file path webapps/ass2/WEB-INF/classes/User.class*
>
> ...
>
> `<%@page import="mypck.User" %>`

This doesn't match. The `User.class` has got to be placed in the `mypck` folder representing the package. Fix it accordingly: `webapps/ass2/WEB-INF/classes/mypck/User.class`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using *scriptlets* is discouraged since a decade. I recommend to take a JSP pause and invest some time in learning taglibs and EL. With EL, you can just show the username like follows:

```
<p>Welcome, ${userBean.name}</p>
```

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Answer (score 0):

Your import is correct syntax-wise, but is the package declaration correct?

Comment: what should the package declaration be?

Comment: On the top of your class (User.java) you will see something like package xxx.yyy.zzz.User; that should transform into: <%@page import="xxx.yyy.zzz.User" %>, if you don't see the package declaration, then it should be <%@page import="User" %>